# Using of/for with need

Tags: prepositions

When using "need" is it *of* or *for*

For example:

> **no need for extra money**

or

> **no need of extra money**

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is “There is no real difference.”

The long answer is “There is a difference of nuance caused by the etymology and history of the prepositions and grammatical cases in Old English.”

To understand the difference it is also necessary to understand that “to have the need for/of” is a delexical verb. The verb “have” has no meaning without its object noun (extra money.)

Thus “He has no need for/of extra money” = “He does not need extra money.”

(Compare “took” in “I took a shower” = “I showered.”)

The distinctions in prepositions are notoriously difficult to describe. **For** and **of** both imply different aspects of the dative of association.

**For** describes its object as passing from one person to another – “He bakes/buys a cake **for** her.” The cake passes **from** him to her.

**Of** is a cognate of “**from**” and describes the origin of its object. “The outlaw is Robin of Nottingham” = “The outlaw is Robin from Nottingham” = “The outlaw is Robin whose origin is in Nottingham”

(Compare The blade was of silver > the origin of the blade was the metal we call silver.)

*He has no need **for** extra money* – “for extra money” is an adjectival prepositional modifier – it tells you that there is {no need} that **is passing** from him to whoever it might be who would be giving it to him.

*He has no need **of** extra money* – “of extra money” – it informs you that there is not a need that **originates** in money

Comment: Fantastic Explanation!

Comment: short comments are not allowed, but mine would be: "wow"

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The usage is slightly different, e.g. "I am in need of money" versus "I have a need for money"

The phrase "**in** need **of**" can be considered a unit.

The phrase "**a** need **for**" can also be considered a unit.

> "I am in need of money" means that I need money *right now*.
>
> "I have a need for money." means that I like money and I always need
> (want) it.

The same distinction is true for "***No need of/for***"

There are exceptions, as I am sure others will point out in the comments.

---

**2.** I would say that "need of" is somewhat old-fashioned. This seems to be confirmed by the following Google Ngram.

[image]
https://bit.ly/2ZB5Xbu

How do we say it these days? ***I need money.***